# How to convert List<Map<String,Object>> to byte[]

Tags: byte, arrays

I have list of data fetched from database and is stored as `List<Map<String,Object>>`. Now I need to write this data in an excel sheet for which I need to convert it as byte[]. How can I convert this?
Can anyone help on this?

Comment: this is way to imprecise. also why not write a CSV file?

Comment: @hoijui. Thankyou for the response. Can I ask you to explain in detail or provide me some example. It would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: how to solve the details of your problem is your task. CSV is a very simple format, explained well online. how to write a text file in java can also be found in many tutorials online. if you are a programmer, it is best to learn programming by trying to solve as much as possible yourself. otherwise, you will just always be frustrated. if you don't like to try to solve problems yourself, you should run away fast from whatever it is that needs you to code.

Comment: @hoijui. Thanks much. I will try solving it.